# Open encrypted PDF in ubuntu

Tags: encryption, pdf, certificates

I have a pdf which is encrypted using a public key algorithm. I also have the corresponding certificate in *.p12 format. I am able to open this pdf in windows after installing this certificate (using install PFX option).

But I am unable to find equivalent procedure in Ubuntu for the same. I have tried importing this certificate in chromium as well as firefox settings. But the pdf doc is not opening in browser as well as any pdf viewer(like evince, qpdfview and foxit reader).
Can anybody tell the correct procedure for this?

Comment: Can you use [`pk12util`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/pk12util.1.html) to import the certificate file to Ubuntu?

Comment: I used this command: pk12util -i /tmp/cert-files/crt.p12 -d sql:/<some dir path>. But its only creating *.db file in specified dir. Its still not working. Which command should be used?